# Highchart's y axis overlay with another

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

This is how my chart looks currently:

[image]

My function to create y axis is following:

```
  function generateYAxises(){
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < af.currentDataDetails.length; i++) {
        var yAxis = {
          showEmpty: false,
          title: {
            text: af.currentDataDetails[i].paramDisplayName,
            style: {
              color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i]
            }
          },
          labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
              color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i]
            }
          },
          offset: 70
        };
        result.push(yAxis);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

How to cope with overlay effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the same [`offset`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.offset) for all of your y-axes. I'd either try not setting it at all (as per my experience the Highcharts correctly lay out the axes side-by-side in that case), or incrementing the offset per axis.

... and here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yydfa6g/1/) showing that explicit `offset`s close together will indeed cause overlap.